# DevOps Four Key Metrics - Determine the change lead time from Jira tickets, Git commits and Jenkins pipelines

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jira, devops

I would like to register the change lead time (one of the [four key metrics](https://www.thoughtworks.com/radar/techniques/four-key-metrics)) of different Jira tickets, that is to say, register the time since a ticket is created until it is fishished and the corresponding code reaches production.

The ticket creation event would be detected in Jira with a plugin, sending its information (`{issueNumber: APP-001, creationDate: 2019-xx-xx...}`) to a datatake.

The feature would be considered finished when it starts a pipeline execution that reaches production:

1. Dev commits code using a comment referencing the issue `#APP-001 Finished feature` and pushes it to master.
2. The Jenkins pipeline passes by different stages (build, test, deploy-uat) and finally executes the deproy-prod stage). If it finishes ok, it should register in the datalake the finished features included in the deployment.

To get the finished features I was thinking of getting commits that where included, examing their commit messages looking for the references to Jira tickets (APP-xxx).

However, my question is how can I get this list of commits? I have access to the whole git commit history but how can I get only the new commits added by the last push?

Comment: You can't get a list of commits added by the last push at any time. Only time to get that is using [githooks](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) at the time of doing a pull or push. I would suggest using tags to determine the list of chances instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a straightforward way to determine the set of commits included in the current Jenkins build using the Jenkins API.

Inside the Jenkins pipeline execution we can call the Jenkins API (`https://jenkins.myorg.com/job/[MY_GROUP]/job/[MY_PROJECT]/job/master/[BUILD_NUMBER]/api/json?tree=changeSets[\*[\*]]`) to get the information of the changeset that includes the list of new commits.